# Is it possible to get an EC2 instances tags using the metadata api?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Also if it's not possible to get the tags using the metadata api do you get charged for calling the EC2 web service from an EC2 instance? i.e. would it be better to just encode the tags in the user data which is available internally for free.

Comment: What's the point in that tiny edit when this question was answered ages ago?

Comment: for readability; I'm coming back to this question six years after it was answered, and agree that the edit was constructive. "The title says it all" is rather redundant and doesn't help other users determine whether your question is specifically what they're looking for.

Comment: Wow, chipping in another 5 years later. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: People come and people go, but Stack Exchange questions live forever (or until a mod/admin deletes them at least) ;)

Comment: Yes, I still get rep trickling in for a Silverlight answer from years ago. It makes me sad that people are still using Silverlight. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instance metadata does not contain tag information. See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-categories.html for the list of metadata categories.

The metadata does include the instance id which can be used along with the EC2 API to retrieve the tags.

There should be no concern about price for calling the EC2 APIs. You are not charged by the API call for EC2.

Comment: Charges for the instance are for instance-hours and bandwidth. But bandwidth is not charged for data transferred within the same region (i.e. US-East) for API calls. "There is no Data Transfer charge between Amazon EC2 and other Amazon Web Services within the same region (i.e. between Amazon EC2 US West and Amazon S3 in US West)." [link](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/#dataXferPricing)

Answer (score 1):

AWS has recently announced support for instance tags in Instance Metadata Service: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/01/instance-tags-amazon-ec2-instance-metadata-service/

If you have the [tag metadata option enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#work-with-tags-in-IMDS:%7E:text=To%20allow%20access%20to%20tags%20in%20instance%20metadata%20at%20launch%20using%20the%20AWS%20CLI) for an instance, you can simply run:

```bash
$ TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 900"`
$ curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance
Tag1-Key
Tag2-Key

$ curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance/Tag1_Key
Tag1_Value
```